# How could I set up default filter value for ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid with server side datasource, server side filtering. I would like to use querystring parameters to set default filter values for this grid.
How could I do it?

I found gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance, but my issue in this case the grid set ajax request just after the initialization, then send another ajax for that default filter value, so I have two ajax request, instead of only one at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue. I looked all around and found that it doesn't seem to be possible to initialize ag-grid with column state, filter state, or sort state; instead these need to be applied after `onGridReady`, which triggers the extra AJAX requests.

I've made a feature request for this to be added to ag-grid in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1785).

Comment: could you plz help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450872/search-function-of-agsetcolumnfilter-customization?noredirect=1#comment115715821_65450872