# Search function customization

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

which shows a table with its column.
What I need is building a search lookup function instead of the default filter function, so that ON The List of Values in Mini Filter window and NOT the whole table:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If typing the full name Michael then the table will be filtered by Michael, OR if I type the phone number then the name of Michael will be filtered by Michael. in other words.

I dont what to change the values of the filter to filter based tokens, and i also dont want to change the columns values to column based token, but i only need that if the input of the user in the search field is inside the tokens then returns the key of the token and show it to the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a lookup search functin using ag-grid CustomFilterComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410978/how-to-build-a-lookup-search-functin-using-ag-grid-customfiltercomponent)

Comment: No, i need the search function of mini filter window and not that wohle table.

Answer (score 1):

Got a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7nxjwvLJRZWTvOKK). Note that I'm not very familiar with Angular, so the code might seem weird.

I defined a custom filter, called `CustomSetFilter`, in which the text input functions as a search field for the `tokens` of each checkbox as defined in `filterData`. If the input is empty, all checkboxes appear. If not, only checkboxes that have a token equal to the input's value (ignoring case) will show up. This can be seen in the `onChange()` function.

Comment: Thanks i will check your solution, is it possible to leave that filter symbole above of the column `Athlete` instead of hiding it?

Comment: You mean the [floating filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filter-component)? It's a different component which I'll have to provide separately.

Comment: no no, i mean i you look at the column country, the symbole looks different from the Athlete filter symbole. I need the same symbole as country on top of athlete please

Comment: is it possible please?

Comment: Like, when the filter is active? They look the same to me. If you uncheck a checkbox on each column, the filter icon appears, and it's the same on both columns.

Comment: what do you mean by unchecking a checkbox?